# After moving hard drive to new computer, networking is not detected

Tags: installation, networking

I want to move my ubuntu installation to a new computer, I move the hard drive and boot but the networking is not found.

If I install on the new computer from scratch, networking is fine.

What can I do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try up the network interface on the new computer: 'sudo ifup eth0' or eth1

Comment: Achu has a possible solution(I would think ethX+1 where X is the last interface you had previously).  Another possibility is that you don't have the networking driver that is required for the chipset on the new computer.  This is even more true if you recompiled your kernel to optimize boot time and/or performance.

Comment: @fossfreedom Marcus has [pointed out](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/84191) that this appears to be [solved here](http://www.serenux.com/2009/11/howto-fix-a-missing-eth0-adapter-after-moving-ubuntu-server-from-one-box-to-another/). If this question is reopened, I can post an answer summarizing the information there (and linking to it for reference), if Marcus does not himself do so.

Comment: @EliahKagan - question has been reopened - ping me in chat and I'll clean up the comments.